# Why pushing array into another array merges the elements instead of putting them in separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array into which I push new values iteratively, at the end of each iteration I want the array formed to be inserted into new array.
Ex: if at the end of first iteration array=[1,2,3,4], then bigarray=[[1,2,3,4]].
After 2nd iteration, if array=[5,6,7,8], then bigarray=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]] and so on.

So basically bigarray is to contain a list of arrays out of which I can obtain arrays.
ex: bigarray[0] should give me a array [1,2,3,4]

What I am doing now is array.push(some values) and at the end bigarray.push(array). Doing this merges all the values into a single array like this
bigarray=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] out of which I can separate first array and second array.

piece of code:

```
            var array=[];


            for(var i=0; i<range;i++){
                var arraychart=[];
                var jan= resp.ChartDataList[i].jan;
                arraychart.push(jan);
                var feb= resp.ChartDataList[i].feb;
                arraychart.push(feb);
                var mar= resp.ChartDataList[i].mar;
                arraychart.push(mar);
                var apr= resp.ChartDataList[i].apr;
                arraychart.push(apr);
                var may= resp.ChartDataList[i].may;
                arraychart.push(may);
                var jun= resp.ChartDataList[i].jun;
                arraychart.push(jun);
                //var jan= resp.ChartDataList[i].jan;
                array.push(arraychart);
                alert (arraychart);

            }
            alert(array);
```

How do I achieve the above desired result??

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Please show some real code. I assume that you do something like `array.push(1, 2, 3)` while should be doing `array.push([1, 2, 3])`

Comment: I am not pushing hard coded data. Ia m pushing a array variable iteratively into anotheer array variable. Kindly check the code I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `array.push` in this way (array.push([1,2,3])) instead of (array.push(1,2,3))

```
var bigarray = [];

bigarray.push( [1,2,3,4] );
bigarray.push( [5,6,7,8] );

console.log(bigarray); // prints [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your code, you don't have problems in your code, just print the array using `console.log` instead of `alert`, because `alert` will call `.toString()` of the big array, and flatten it

Comment: I am not pushing hard coded data. Ia m pushing a array variable iteratively into anotheer array variable. Kindly check the code I updated

Comment: Ya mshaaban..I tried using console.log and my data seems to appear in desired form. However it is shown now in the following form [Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]] I suppose the 1 indicates one array inside each of the 6 elements. But how can I now access this array index wise. If I use [0] on this aaray, it returns again Array[6] as it has 6 elements. But how to see the element of this Array[6].

Comment: In short, I mean how do we access elements of an array-element of an array.

Comment: If I stored the first element of  [Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1], Array[1]]  in an array X and then try to aceess its first element as X[0]. I am getting the same value of X and X[0]. Why is so?

Comment: Just access it like this: `array[0][0], array[0][1], ...array[N-1][M-1]`

Answer (score 0):

U can try something like this

```
bigArrray[bigArray.length] = subArray
```

But...

```
bigArrray.push([1,2,3])
```

...works as well for me